# Using D3.xml to plot a tree layout

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

In d3.js, I have seen the use of d3.JSON to use a JSON for building a tree layout.
I have also worked with csv files, to first convert those in JSON by using d3.csv and d3.nest.
But,while taking a XML data dource using d3.xml, can anyone suggest how to proceed for making a tree layout without converting xml data to JSON first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d3.xml` (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_xml) and then parse the content using javascript

Resource on Javascript xml parsing:

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript.